# call a property setter dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x

`self.__dict__.update` resp. `self.__dict__....` is overwriting the `serial setter` function:

```
class Overwrite:
  serial_ = None

  @property
  def serial(self):
    print("get serial...")
    return self.serial_

  @serial.setter
  def serial(self, v):
    print("set serial...")
    self.serial_ = v

  def demo(self):
    test = {'serial': 'D1D297C1E8839EF2C0E69EF709653C05'}
    self.__dict__.update(test)


ow = Overwrite()
ow.demo()
print(ow.serial)
```

I would like to find a way to set the `serial setter` function dynamically. Can someone help me?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Why can't you just do `self.serial = 'D1....'`?

Comment: Note also that both your `__init__` method and the declaration of `serial` at the class level are pointless and should be removed.

Comment: What is your goal? Is your property not working?  If you're using Python2, you'll want to make sure you explicitly inherit from `object` IE `class Overwrite(object):`

Comment: @Daniel Roseman because I receive one or more dictionary like `{'serial':...` or `{'foo':...`. In the serial example I'd like to modify the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setattr`:

```
for k, v in test.items():
    setattr(self, k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have edited the `__setattr__` function and need to re-implement the behaviour of checking for property setters, you can also do this:

```py
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if (
            key in vars(type(self))
            and isinstance(vars(type(self))[key], property)
            and vars(type(self))[key].fset is not None
        ):
            vars(type(self))[key].fset(self, value)
```